# add a year and subtract a day, using datepart in my query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date

```
Where (DYYYY = (year( getdate() +1)))DatePart(month, GETDATE())) + '/' + DatePart(day, GetDate())) -1 + '/' + DatePart(year, GetDate())) +1)
```

I am having trouble running a query where i can use yesterdays date, but next year for projections.

Comment: I suspect you might want to reformat your query to get useful answers.  What you have isn't valid; could you break it up into multiple logical lines?

Comment: yeah i want to separate the month the day and the year

Answer (score 6):

Will this give you what you're looking for?

```
DATEADD(yy, 1, DATEADD(dd, -1, getdate()))
```

If you want to exclude the time component, then you can use a variation like this

```
DATEADD(yy, 1, DATEADD(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), -1))
```

Comment: for some reason these are not working for me. I want it in the original getdate format just adding a year and subtracting a day. However, when i try these in my query i get no return.

Comment: What is the data type and sample value for DYYYY in your question?  My solution returns a DATETIME data type.